# Java method argument in calling and caller methods

Tags: java

Just simple reverse string method.
FYI, correct methods are reverseString1 and reverseString2, 
but revereStirng3() doesn't give me correct output.
I think this is because of method args and return values are stored in the Stack and related with this concept. But I don't clearly understand why revereStirng3() doesn't work correctly.
Please let me know whey this is not working.

This is what I understand, and please correct me if I'm wrong.
1. main() calls revereStirng3(A) where this passing argument array A is stored in the stack frame for the main().

1. revereStirng3(char[] A) where this passed argument array A is stored in revereStirng3's method frame which means main's A[] is copied to revereStirng3's stack frame's method argument A[].
2. After reverse, revereStirng3 creates new String(A) for return String.
3. Then, I thought, in the main, returned new String(A) is correctly print reversed string, but actually not.

   // Given a string "abcdef", reverse it. so output should be "fedcba"

   ```
   import java.util.*;

   public class ReverseString {

       static String revereStirng3(char[] A) {    
           int n = A.length;       

           for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
               char temp = A[n-i-1];
               A[n-i-1] = A[i];
               A[i] = temp;
           }

           return new String(A);
       }

       static void revereStirng1(char[] A) {
           int n = A.length;       

           for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
               char temp = A[n-i-1];
               A[n-i-1] = A[i];
               A[i] = temp;
           }
       }

       static String revereStirng2(String str) {
           char[] A = str.toCharArray();
           int n = A.length;       

           for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
               char temp = A[n-i-1];
               A[n-i-1] = A[i];
               A[i] = temp;
           }

           return String.valueOf(A);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           String s = "abcdef";
           char[] A = s.toCharArray();

           System.out.print( revereStirng3(A) + "\n" );   **// print out "abcdef"**
           System.out.println( "" );

           revereStirng1(A);                              // print out "fedcba"
           for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++)
               System.out.print( A[i] );
           System.out.println( "" );

           System.out.print( revereStirng2(s) + "\n" );    // print out "fedcba"
           System.out.println( "" );


       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Are you sure the methods are called in the order you write here? I can make sense of the result if you calculate `revereString3` after calculating `revereString2`, but not otherwise.

Comment: Got
fedcba
abcdef
fedcba
Which is what it is expected: reversed, reverse reversed=original, reverse

Answer (score 1):

Ok, given that zenbeni has got the real results, here is what is happening.

An array in Java is an object, so in `revereString1` and `revereString3` you get **a copy of the reference to the array**. So, your changes modify the original array, which (after the first method execution) has been reversed. Of course, the second execution reverses it again, so you get the reverse of the reverse, which is the original String.

Try using a new, locally defined array to create the reversed String and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

From apache commons:

```
StringUtil.reverse(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your method and executed it

`System.out.println(revereStirng3("abcdef".toCharArray()));`

on the result was

`fedcba`.

The problem is located in the main function:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abcdef";
        char[] A = s.toCharArray();

        System.out.println( revereStirng3(A));  // print out "abcdef"**

        revereStirng1(A);                       

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(A));   // print out "fedcba"

        System.out.println(revereStirng2(s));   // print out "fedcba"
    }
```

Your comments do not show the true.

The valid output for it would be

```
fedcba
[a,b,c,d,e,f]
fedcba
```

And this is because you operate on the same array for three test cases. In the second step you pass allready reversed array as input. This results that the order has not changed.